# Got 'Configuration for rule "no-unused-expressions" is invalid' on linux but not on osx

Tags: linux, macos, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

It is the dependency in package.json

```
"babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
"eslint": "3.17.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "14.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.10.0",
```

When I run `npm run lint` on a `Linux 3.13.0-107-generic`

```
/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/best-practices.js:
    Configuration for rule "no-unused-expressions" is invalid:
    Value "data["0"].allowTaggedTemplates" has additional properties.

Referenced from: /home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/index.js
Referenced from: airbnb
Referenced from: /home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/.eslintrc
Error: /home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/best-practices.js:
    Configuration for rule "no-unused-expressions" is invalid:
    Value "data["0"].allowTaggedTemplates" has additional properties.

Referenced from: /home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/index.js
Referenced from: airbnb
Referenced from: /home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/.eslintrc
    at validateRuleOptions (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:109:15)
    at Object.keys.forEach.id (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:156:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.validate (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:155:35)
    at load (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:529:19)
    at configExtends.reduceRight.e (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:391:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:362:28)
    at load (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:536:22)
    at configExtends.reduceRight.e (/home/ubuntu/webview/analytics2/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:391:36)
```

I suppose the error is due to `Configuration for rule "no-unused-expressions" is invalid:` as shown in the above stack trace.

It is the content of `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "expect": true,
    "URLSearchParams": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [2, 80, 4, {"ignoreComments": true}],
    "valid-jsdoc": 2,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "import/extensions": 0
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

However I cannot reproduce this error on my OSX MBP.

How can I fix it issue?

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into the same issue today. My suggestion is to run npm outdated and upgrade the eslint related packages.

For me, it was upgrading eslint to 3.18.0 and eslint-plugin-react to 6.10.3 that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue today. I did the update of all needed packages. But it didn't help. Then I switched forth and back between Node.js interpreters (versions) and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the react-scripts module helped me.

Comment: could you please specify which versions did you update to? so that we know what works. thanks,